# Two points with same distance (ratio) to M points in N dimensional space (M>N)

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Suppose I have two points A and B and another M points $(P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_M)$ spread out in N dimensional space (M > N). The distance of A to the other M points are represented by the vector $\mathbf{v}_A = (d^A_{1}, d^A_{2}, \cdots, d^A_{M})$, where $d^A_{i}$ represent the distance between A and $P_i$. $\mathbf{v}_B$ is defined similarly.

My questions are: does $\mathbf{v}_A = \mathbf{v}_B$ mean A and B are the same point? Can two distinct points exist so that $\mathbf{v}_A = k \mathbf{v}_B$, where $k$ is a constant not equal to 1?

Comment: I assumed he wants the points to span the space, and also, you're solution to 2 is incorrect - the ratio is not a scalar multiple.

Comment: What does "the distance of A to the other M points" mean?

Comment: @LukePeachey and Aretino Thanks of the comment, I have updated my description according to your feedback.